# Replace number with subquery result in string

Tags: regex, postgresql

Let's say I've got a text field that looks like this:

```
'number: 123 number: 456'
```

I'd like to be able to replace those numbers with the result of this query:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE number = 123;
SELECT name FROM table WHERE number = 456;
```

To return this:

```
'number: apple number: banana'
```

I've got this query to identify the integer components of the string:

```
select regexp_matches('number: 123 number: 456', '[0-9]{3}', 'g')::int[];
```

And I've tried to use that query as a subquery in a replace statement, but I'm not having any luck:

```
select regexp_replace('number: 123 number: 456', '[0-9]{3}', (select name from topics where id::text = regexp_matches('number: 123 number: 456', '[0-9]{3}', 'g')));
```

Comment: What exactly does "not having any luck" mean here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that you can do that in single line when you want to replace multiple values, but here is one solution how you can do that:

```
SELECT string_agg(strrpl, ' ') AS myString
FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN t1.name IS NULL 
            THEN tbl.foo 
            ELSE regexp_replace(tbl.foo, t1.id::text, t1.name) END AS strrpl
FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT foo FROM regexp_split_to_table((SELECT string 
                                                   FROM t2 
                                                   WHERE id = 1), E'\\s+') AS foo) as tbl
ON tbl.foo ~~ t1.id::text) AS boo;
```

Here i placed you string into the table and than select them from there.

Also I create [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c26f/52) so you can check how it's work...

The main trick here is that I split string into a table. This line of code:

```
SELECT foo FROM regexp_split_to_table((SELECT string 
                                       FROM t2 
                                       WHERE id = 1), E'\\s+') AS foo
```

Basically this query separate string into a table where each word from string become one row into the table. [Look HERE!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c26f/45)

Than I make one RIGHT JOIN (because i select FROM t1 first) and that connect each name from t1 with corresponding number in table we got when we split a string to table. [Look HERE!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c26f/48)

After that I replace values in column we got when we split string (foo table) with the words from t1, but in case when value in column we select from t1 is NULL we want to keep value from column foo... This line here

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.name IS NULL 
            THEN tbl.foo 
            ELSE regexp_replace(tbl.foo, t1.id::text, t1.name) END
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c26f/51) for that...

And at the end we need to create again one string from this column we got. We use string_agg function...

GL!